# load dojo.js on my web server

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, xampp

refer to the http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/hello_dojo/demo/slideInGreeting.php
it is totally working fine.

The I copy the html and try to run it on my local apache.
it also working!

But when I try to load the same dojo.js on my web server, it won't work...!!?
(load the dojo.js on my localhost web server, instead of ajax.googleapis.com)
Here is my file structure, html and errors.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try "dojo/dojo.js" instead of "js/dojo/dojo.js" as source.

Comment: It is not working. the html file is not under the folder js. my path to refer to dojo.js is correct.

Comment: ok, in the picture it looked like the html file was in the js-dir.

Comment: Thanks for reading, ^_^, I insist not to use CDN, because we have many intranet user cannot access internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Finally I got it myself.
The dojo.js is only the base, if I use other module of dojo I have to add it on my need.

So I need to download all the dojo modules from:
http://dojotoolkit.org/download/

download the zip file --> Release:tar.gz (7.9MB)zip (12MB)

unzip it , then I can find all the files, include fx.js.
[image]

Finally , it working on my server now!